# Anychart: Scroll function

Tags: javascript, anychart

Good afternoon, I am doing some tests with the Gantt chart, but the more range the chart has, the cells of the days appear smaller, that is, if I have a range of two years, the columns of the days look small.

As you can see, I tried to put a scroller on it as the documentation says, however I get no error, but the scroll is not applied. I want the day columns to look big, and have the horizontal scroll that leads to the end of the range. If you could give me a little support. thanks greetings.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
    // create data
    var data = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Development",
      actualStart: "2018-01-15",
      actualEnd: "2018-03-10",
      children: [{
          id: "1_1",
          name: "Analysis",
          actualStart: "2018-01-15",
          actualEnd: "2018-01-25"
        },
        {
          id: "1_2",
          name: "Design",
          actualStart: "2018-01-20",
          actualEnd: "2018-02-04"
        },
        {
          id: "1_3",
          name: "Meeting",
          actualStart: "2018-02-05",
          actualEnd: "2018-02-05"
        },
        {
          id: "1_4",
          name: "Implementation",
          actualStart: "2018-02-05",
          actualEnd: "2018-02-24"
        },
        {
          id: "1_5",
          name: "Testing",
          actualStart: "2018-02-25",
          actualEnd: "2018-02-26"
        }
      ]
    }];
    // create a data tree
    var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-tree");
    // create a chart
    var chart = anychart.ganttProject();

    chart.dataGrid().column(0).enabled(false);
    chart.dataGrid().column(1).width(400);
    //header names
    var column_2 = chart.dataGrid().column(1);
    column_2.title().text("Houses Reservations");
    // Header dates
    var header = chart.getTimeline().header();
    header.fill("#232159");
    header.fontColor("#fff");

    var scroll = anychart.column();

    // turn on X Scroller
    scroll.xScroller(true);



    var scale = chart.xScale();

    // Set zoom levels.
    scale.zoomLevels([
      [{
          unit: 'day',
          count: 1
        },
        {
          unit: 'month',
          count: 1
        }
      ]
    ]);
    // set the data
    chart.data(treeData);
    // set the container id
    chart.container("container");
    // initiate drawing the chart
    chart.draw();
    // fit elements to the width of the timeline
    chart.fitAll();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to enable the scroller manually, it will appear automatically when the Gantt chart timeline exceeds the width of the container. To deal with the size of the day period, you could use the `zoomTo()` method and then the `fitAll()` method to return to the full picture.

```
// add functions to scale your chart up and down 
function fitAll() {
 chart.fitAll();
}
function zoomOnADay(){
 chart.zoomTo("day", 5, "first-visible-date");
}
```

Take a look at a sample here: https://playground.anychart.com/0uIGwoWQ/1